# How to cancel Validation when switching TabPages

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, tabcontrol

I'm writing an application in c# .NET 4.0. I've implemented TDI using TabControl and TabPages. On each TabPage there is a bunch of TextBoxes, ComboBoxes, Grids, Checkboxes etc. Each control has Validation and Validated event attached. Form, TabControl and each Tabpage have CausesValidation set to false. On each TabPage there are also some Panels, each has CausesValidation also set to false. Other controls (TextBoxes, CheckBoxes) have CausesValidation set to true. In this way, I'm able to switch between TabPages independently. However, when on one Tab, some control fails validation, controls on the rest of TabPages are prevent to receive focus. I've implemented onSelecting and onDeselecting events for each TabPage, so one way is to switch off CausesValidation on controls on TabPage, which is going to be hidden, and switch on CausesValidation on all controls on TabPage which is now in the front. Is there a better way to achieve this functionality?

---

Added:

I want validation to take place for each tab independently. Result of validation of one tab should not affect behaviour of other tabs. Changing AutoValidate property to EnableAllowFocusChange doesn't work - I still want to prevent changing focus if validation fails, but it should be limited only to this particular tab. If control is going to lost focus as a result of switching to the other tab, it should be allowed.

It is hard to provide source code, but here is a sample project that explains the problem.

http://www.speedyshare.com/T49DR/SampleProject.zip

Comment: Please provide source code exhibiting the problem.

Comment: It's not very clear "when" you want to validate the controls.  You can always change the form's AutoValidate property to EnableAllowFocusChange.

Comment: Post has been edited.

Comment: Then change it to `tabControl1.CausesValidation = true;`

Comment: Well... setting `tabControl1.CausesValidation = true;` makes me unable to switch to the second tab.

Comment: Well, you already solved it based on your OnSelecting and OnDeselecting tab events.  Use [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) for questions like `is there a better way?`

Comment: ok, second, simpler way is first to check in both Validating and Validated `if(ownerTab.ContainsFocus)` and then proceed with validating etc... but maybe there is a better, more elegant solution...  LarsTech: thanks :)